# What is Unzip_LRU list?

Tags: mysql, innodb, lru, bufferpool

I am learning mysql buffer pool.

I know that buffer pools have lru list and unzip lru list in the InnoDB storage engine.

I don't know why InnoDB buffer pool use the unzip lru list.

Why use unzip lru list and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate and search on data the page has to be uncompressed. The notion of compressed started with `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` tables. When ordinary pages are uncompress too they use use the same list.